# USRP2 FPGA debugging

Tags: verilog, fpga, gnuradio, usrp

I have added some functionality  in the FPGA code( Verilog) in USRP2. I would like to debug the code. Can you please suggest, how to debug the FPGA code .

I donot want to write the testbench for the module. Is it possible that I could write to a buffer in the FPGA code and read this buffer from the firmware and read it from the serial console of the USRP2.

Any hints/ direction would be highly helpful.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Are you saying you tried using this design without any simulation at all?

Comment: Why do you not want to write a testbench and simulate the design?  Simulation usually ends up being far less work than a add test points, build, test and repeat flow.  Especially the first time you are bringing up a given function.

Comment: Also, what type of access does the serial console currently provide?  If you can read and write registers in the HDL design you can add your own debug registers and then read and write to them using the serial console.  You can also bring some signals out to test points on the physical board and look at them with an oscilloscope, logic analyzer or if they are slow enough even a multi-meter.  Chipscope is another option for gaining visibility of internal signals.

Comment: No. I have built the model in Simulink using Xilinx library and generated the HDL Netlist in Verilog and I am integrating this in the USRP2 FPGA code. I have done simulation in Simulink.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your code in 2 different ways, one is using the debug port available on the unit the second one is to use the JTAG port and use the ChipScope to debug your code.

This is from the GR site: http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/USRP2UserFAQ#Is-there-a-JTAG-port

> Is there a JTAG port?
>
> Yes, there is a standard JTAG header on the board connected to the
>   FPGA and a CPLD, but you may not need it. Since the FPGA is programmed
>   from the SD Card by the bootstrapping CPLD, the main utility of the
>   JTAG port is to reprogram the CPLD. You may be able to use the JTAG
>   port with ChipScope.

And this is the answer Nick Foster replied to on the GR mailing list:

> There's a debug port (MICTOR connector) on the USRP2 (J301) which you
>   can route signals to for debugging. It's connected to the 32-bit wire
>   "debug" in u2_core.v. Just connect signals you're interested in to
>   debug and use a logic analyzer.

BR,
Farhad